# Calculate phase lag index between two time series

Tags: matlab, functional-dependencies, phase

I want to calculate phase lag index as defined in this paper using Matlab:
http://kurage.nimh.nih.gov/tomh/PLI.pdf

I have two equal-length time-series a and b. I am not sure how to do so. What I have done so far is:

PLI = abs(mean(sign(phaseLag(a, b))));

I have two questions:

1. Did I understand the formula of PLI correctly? (I am doubtful.)
2. If so, how to calculate phase lag?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to compute the phase lag is to use xcorr.

If you type

```
help xcorr
```

you will see an example that does exactly that.